# Google maps not displayed in website

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am currently stuck on getting google maps to display on a site. This worked in a dev environment after a while. I came to put this into live and thought that I would just need the API key in the src

What I have is

```
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API CODE HERE&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    initialize();

    function initialize() {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            codeAddress("@Model.Postcode, @Model.Address");
        });
        }

    var geocoder;
    var map;

    function codeAddress(address) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 17,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                // create a marker
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Latitude: ' + results[0].geometry.location.Ya + ' Longitude :' + results[0].geometry.location.Za
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

But this only produces the error of

This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You first have to obtain an API key from the website and replace it with the "MY_API CODE HERE" part

Comment: Yes I have an API key that I use. I just plop it into that section

Answer (score 0):

That should be working, just because we all make mistakes, are you sure you copied the API key correctly? You need to make sure the trailing '&' is still in there after you add the key.

You could also try generating another key and using that. The process for doing that is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key